# Confused by solution to Question 2 Part viii of Chapter 14 in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Question 2 of Chapter 14 in Spivak's *Calculus* reads as follows:

> For each of the following $f$, if $F(x)=\int_0^xf$, at which points $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$?

Part (viii) of Question 2 uses the function:

> $f(x)=1$ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ in $\mathbb N$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

The solution manual for this problem reads as:

> All $x$ not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ for some natural number $n$ [...are points where $F'(x)=f(x)$]

From this proposed solution, Spivak suggests that $F'(0)=f(0)$ (more specifically, it should be $F'^+(0)=f(0)$...but for his problems, this is usually implicit).

However, I believe $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ (because there is no right limit) and, moreover, the intermediate value property is not upheld for any $\delta_n=\frac{1}{n} \gt 0$ on the interval $[0,\delta_n]$. Therefore, I do not think that $0$ should be included in the list of points that exhibit the feature of $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not read the book, I can't speak to what the "rules" are for integration, but it probably falls into one of the two camps below.

**Riemann integral rules** If the book is using Riemann integration then we can construct a series of step functions $(\phi_i,\psi_i)$ such that for every $x$
\begin{align}
   \phi_i(z) \leq f(z) \leq \psi_i(z) \text{ for all } z \in [0,x] \\
   \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x\psi_i(z)-\phi(z) dz = 0 \\
   \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x\psi_i(z)dz = \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x\phi_i(z)dz = 0
\end{align}
This will show that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(z) dz = 0$ for every $x$, and therefore since $F$ is constant the derivative of $F$ is $F'(x) = 0$ for every $x$, in particular for $x = 0$ we have $F'(0) = 0 = f(0)$.

I'll construct the series now, its a bit messy to do this and a good exercise to try for yourself first.

If $x \leq 0$ then just set $\phi_i = \psi_i = 0$ and all of the properties are satisfied.

So let $x > 0$ and let $n_0$ be the smallest positive integer such that $1/n_0 \leq x$. Set $\phi_i = 0$ for every $i$. Set
\begin{equation}
    \psi_i(x) = \mathbb{1}\left [x \leq \frac{1}{n_0+i+1}\right ] + \sum_{k = n_0}^{n_0+i} \mathbb{1}\left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1/k -1/(k+1)}{2i} \leq x \leq 1/k \right]
\end{equation}
This function may look like a beast but there is an intuition to its construction. The $n_0$ trick makes it so we can ignore the bad points of $f$ which are outside of $[0,x]$. After that each term in the sum handles exactly one point $1/(n_0 + k) \in [0,x]$ where $f$ is badly behaved. The leading term handles all the points near the origin with bad behavior. Incrementing $i$ does two things. First it moves one point from the catch-all interval near the origin into the finite sum. Second, it makes the intervals around the bad points even tighter.

One can check that $\psi$ is an appropriate upper bound on $f$ and also
\begin{align}
   \int_0^x \psi_i(z) &= \frac{1}{n_0+i+1}+ \sum_{k=n_0}^{n_0+i} \frac{1}{k} - \left ( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1/k -1/(k+1)}{2i} \right ) \\
    &=\frac{1}{n_0 + i + 1} + \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=n_0}^{n_0 + i} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} \\
    &\leq \frac{1}{n_0 + i + 1} + \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}  \\
   &= \frac{1}{n_0 + i + 1} + \frac{C}{2i}
\end{align}
where $C = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$ is a finite constant. From this last bound we see that indeed
\begin{equation}
    0 \leq \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x \psi_i(z)dz \leq \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n_0 + i + 1} + \frac{C}{2i} = 0
\end{equation}

**Measure theory rules** If the book is using measure theory to define integrals and we're talking about Lebesgue integration then we have, letting $S = \{1/n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $L$ be the Lebesgue measure, that
\begin{align}
    F(x) = \int_0^x f dL &= \int_{S} fdL + \int_{[0,x] \setminus S} fdL \\
    &= \int_S 1 dL + \int_{[0,x] \setminus S} 0dL \\
    &= 1 \cdot L[S] + 0 \cdot L[[0,x] \setminus S] \\
    & = 1\cdot 0 + 0 \cdot x = 0
\end{align}
which shows that $F(x) = 0$ and since this holds for all $x$ we have $F'(x) = 0$ for all $x$, in particular $F'(0) = 0 = f(0)$.

Comment: My book uses Darboux Integrals (which are equivalent to Riemann, I believe). For your answer, it seems as though you are even including points where there are jump discontinuities. Surely this is incorrect, no?

Comment: My answer mainly focuses on the edge case of $0$, but it actually shows that for all $F'(x) = 0$  and from this it follows that $F'(x) = f(x)$ if and only if $x \neq 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry - I guess this sentence tripped me up: "...and therefore since $F$ is constant the derivative of $F$ is $F'(x) = 0$ for every $x$". I now understand what you meant by this. Even though $F'(1/n)=0$, $f(1/n)=1$ hence $F'(1/n) \neq f(1/n)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using the **Darboux Integral** definition.

---

Consider the function that is defined by the formula:

$f(x)= \begin{cases}1\quad &\text {if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$} \\0 \quad &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

We will show that $\displaystyle \int_a^b f$ is integrable for any $a \leq b \in \mathbb R$. Further, for any $a \leq b$, we have that $\displaystyle \int_a^b f=0$. This shows that $F$ is the constant $0$ and allows one to conclude that $F(0)=f(0)$.

---

Firstly, for any $a \leq 0$ and any $b\geq 1$, we obviously have that $\displaystyle \int_a^0f=0$ and $\displaystyle \int_1^bf=0$, respectively.

Consider when $a=0$ and $b=1$. Next, consider an arbitrary $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Our objective is to construct a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ such that: $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \lt \varepsilon$, which is equivalent to showing that $f|_{[0,1]}$ is integrable. If we can show that this is true, we next note that the set of irrational numbers is dense in $\mathbb R$. Making use of the following set  $S=\left\{s \ |\ \exists n \in \mathbb N: s=\frac{1}{n}\right\}\subset \mathbb Q$, it is clear that $S \cap (\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)=\emptyset$, which means that for any $[t_{i-1},t_i]$, we know that there is an $x \in [t_{i-1},t_i]: f(x)=0$. Therefore, for any $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ described by any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, we know that the corresponding subinterval infimum of $f$, denoted as $m_i $, is equal to $0$, which implies that for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, we have that $L(f,P)=0$. This would then mean that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f=0$ because the integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$ implies that $\displaystyle \sup \{L(f,P):\ P \text{ is a partition of $[a,b]$}\}=\inf \{U(f,P):\ P \text{ is a partition of $[a,b]$}\}$. Finally, if $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f$ exists, then any subset is integrable, meaning that $\displaystyle \int_0^bf$ for $0 \leq b \lt 1$ is integrable. Using the exact logic as before regarding $m_i$'s value, we know that for any partition $S$ of $[0,b]$, all subintervals $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ defined by $S$ will have $f|_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}$'s infimum as $0$. This means that $\displaystyle \int_0^bf = 0$. Therefore, we know that $\displaystyle F(x)= \int_0^x f = 0$ for any $x \geq 0$. Thus, $F$ is a constant and its derivative is $0$ everywhere...note that its full derivative (not just right-derivative) is defined at $x=0$ because $\displaystyle \int_a^0 =0$ for any $a \lt 0$.

---

To construct a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \lt \varepsilon$, we will consider 2 different 'zones' each with the property that their upper-lower sums of $f$ (when restricted to the relevant subintervals comprising each zone) are less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, each. When all such upper-lower sum differences across the 2 zones are added together (while keeping track of each zone's corresponding subinterval partitioning), we will have the necessary partition to show that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \lt \varepsilon$.

*First Zone*

For an arbitrary $\varepsilon \gt 0$, we know that there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that: $\frac{1}{n}\lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Consider any arbitrary partition of $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$: call it $P_1$. On this interval, we know that $U(f,P_1) \leq 1\cdot (\frac{1}{n}-0)$ because $1$ is an upper bound to $f$. Further, as noted earlier, $L(f,P_1)=0$ There $U(f,P_1)-L(f,P_1) \leq \frac{1}{n} \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

*Second Zone*

For our next zone, we will recall the $n$ used in the *first zone*. Because this a finite number, we know that there is a finite list of different $i \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{i} \leq 1$. In particular, $i$ is any element in the set $\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$. Note, then that $\frac{1}{1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ are in this zone. Consider a closed neighborhood $[\frac{1}{i}-\delta,\frac{1}{i}+\delta]$ with $\delta \gt 0$ centered around each $\frac{1}{i}$. There will be $n$ such neighborhoods (two of which will end up only contributing half neighborhoods). We know that on each of these neighborhoods, $f$'s supremum will achieve the value of $M_i=1$. Therefore, the upper-lower sum difference across these closed neighborhoods is no greater than $1\cdot n \cdot 2\delta$, and we need this value to be $\lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Therefore, we compute that $\displaystyle\delta \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{4n}$. For convenience, we will further ensure that none of these neighborhoods overlap. To do this, we will impose an additional length constraint on $\delta$ such that $\delta$ is smaller than the distance between the closest points $\frac{1}{i}$ and $\frac{1}{j}$.

Because the derivative of the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is $g'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$, an application of the Mean Value Theorem (plus some inequality manipulations) will provide us with the following: for any $m \lt n \in \mathbb N$, we have that $\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} \lt \frac{1}{m-1}-\frac{1}{m}$. Therefore, let us stipulate that $\delta \lt \min\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{\varepsilon}{4n}\right)$. Now, union together all numbers that comprised the end points $\frac{1}{i}-\delta$ and $\frac{1}{i}+\delta$ for each $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$: you can disregard $\frac{1}{n}-\delta$ and $\frac{1}{1}+\delta$. Let this set equal $P_2$. Importantly, for the space *between* the neighborhoods, e.g. $[\frac{1}{i}+\delta,\frac{1}{i-1}-\delta]$, it should be obvious that there are no elements of the form $\frac{1}{j}$ in this interval. Therefore, on these subintervals, $f$'s supremum takes on the value $0$, so the upper-lower sum difference on these subintervals is always $0$. Thus, we must have that $U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_2) \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

*Conclusion*

Noting that $P_1=\{0,\cdots,\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $P_2=\{\frac{1}{n},\cdots,1\}$, their union $P=P_1 \cup P_2$ is necessarily a partition of $[0,1]$. Therefore, we can conclude that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\left[U(f,P_1) - L(f,P_1)\right]+\left[U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_2)\right] \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$, as desired. Our previously established logic then follows.